# How do I get my app id in Meta Audience Network?

Tags: admob, facebook-audience-network

Meta has already been successfully linked as a bidding source in Admob for my iOS app. I'm trying to ad Meta as a waterfall ad source as well :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4EH2.png)

As you can see, this requires a System User Access Token. However, when trying to add my app to a System User in order to generate a token for it, there is no app listed :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97rA0.png)

When trying to add an app, I'm asked for an app ID. I'm completely lost and have no id of where to get that app id. Nothing in the help center actually addresses this, it seems.

Edit : I don't know why the images aren't showing, sorry :/

Edit 2 : I also tried creating a facebook app and using that, but the token given just leads to an "Invalid credentials" error in admob.